# Hot to get Azure Search Service query key

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cognitive-search

I need list  query keys from Microsoft.Search/searchServices using PoweShell or API.
What I have investigate till now is:

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Search/searchServices/listQueryKeys" -ResourceGroupName 'resource-group-name' -ResourceName 'resource-name' -ApiVersion '2015-08-19'
```

Returns the array of objects with only names:

```
@{Name=a}
@{Name=query-key-created-from-powershell}
```

I have not found the API to get query keys.
There is easy way to get admin key:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -Action listAdminKeys -ResourceType "Microsoft.Search/searchServices" -ResourceGroupName 'resource-group-name' -ResourceName 'resource-name' -ApiVersion 2015-08-19
```

But no way I can get QueryKeys. This is not working:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -Action listQueryKeys -ResourceType "Microsoft.Search/searchServices" -ResourceGroupName 'resource-group-name' -ResourceName 'resource-name' -ApiVersion 2015-08-19
```

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-manage-powershell) refer only to create or delete Query Key.
How can I get Query Keys as name-key collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the following cmdlet:

```
Get-AzureRmSearchQueryKey -ResourceGroupName "resourceGroupName" -ServiceName "serviceName"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/azurerm.search/get-azurermsearchquerykey?view=azurermps-6.11.0

Check that you have the correct version of Azure PowerShell.

Comment: I have download in my AzureDevOps task 'Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force -Scope CurrentUser
Get-Module -ListAvailable| where {$_.Name -Like '*AzureRM*'}  | Select Name, Version
Install-Module -Name AzureRM -RequiredVersion 6.11.0 -Force -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber
Import-Module AzureRM -Force -Verbose -Scope Local 
Get-Module -ListAvailable| where {$_.Name -Like '*AzureRM*'}  | Select Name, Version' 6.11.0 but AzureRM.Search is not part of it.

Answer (score 1):

To get the query key of the Azure Search service, @Victor Silva 's solution will work fine.

```
Get-AzureRmSearchQueryKey -ResourceGroupName "resourceGroupName" -ServiceName "serviceName"
```

> I have download in my AzureDevOps task 'xxxx' 6.11.0 but AzureRM.Search is not part of it

To your further issue, because the `AzureRM.Search` module is in the preview version, it is not be included in `AzureRM 6.11.0` module, refer to the **Package Details** in this [link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM/6.11.0). So if you want to use this command `Get-AzureRmSearchQueryKey`, you need to install the `AzureRM.Search` independently, use `Install-Module -Name AzureRM.Search -AllowPrerelease`, refer to this [link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Search/0.1.2-preview).

**Update**:

If you want to  list query keys via API, you could use this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchmanagement/querykeys/listbysearchservice).

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Search/searchServices/{searchServiceName}/listQueryKeys?api-version=2015-08-19
```

[image]

Comment: I have failed to execute this in Windows PowerShell as well as in Azure DevOps Task. I can not verify this in AzureDevOps as the task throws  'WARNING: User declined to install module (AzureRM.Search)' while trying to install.

Comment: @Leszek Try to use `-Force` at the end, `Install-Module -Name AzureRM.Search -AllowPrerelease -Force`.

Comment: @Leszek Besides, if you want to use API, you could refer to my update.

Comment: I know API 'way' but thank you for pointing this out. I have tried with -Force.

Comment: As you have mentioned "To get the query key of the Azure Search service, @Victor Silva 's solution will work fine.". Yes, your answer is more complex, but I haven't succeeded to apply it.